# Check if IntentService started on boot is still running

Tags: java, android

Into manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Into application:

```
<service android:name="Myservice"/>
<receiver android:name="com.myapp.Onstart">  <!-- Tested also only .Onstart -->
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
            </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Onstart.java:

```
package com.myapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Onstart extends BroadcastReceiver {    

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){
            context.startService(new Intent(context, Myservice.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Myservice.java:

```
package com.myapp;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class Myservice extends IntentService
{

    public Myservice() {
        super("Myservice");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        int n=0;
        while(true)
        {
            if (i==20) {
               stopSelf();
            }
            i = i++;
            Log.i("Test", "n."+n++);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            { }
        }
    }

}
```

Launching the application manually is shown the Main.java, and I want to know there (in Main.java) if my IntentService `Myservice` is still running. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I know that your question is to whether it's running or not, I do not see why would you need to know. Since IntentService works on demand.

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous
>   requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests
>   through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed,
>   handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself
>   when it runs out of work.

Also, from Context.startService(Intent) call doc:

> If the service is being started or is already running, the
>   ComponentName of the actual service that was started is returned; else
>   if the service does not exist null is returned.

If you must, you can check the startService(Intent) return parameter.

**Edit**: It seems that you need an started service handled solely by you, not the system. This will allow you to have your own stop condition. Please refer to [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and [Services Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingStartedService) on how to use them.

References:
[IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)
[startService(Intent service)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent))
[Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)
[Services Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingStartedService)

Comment: Because maybe my service may not starts on startup. Your code returns false even if service is still running. How to solve it?

Comment: Nvm the loop it only returns system services.

Comment: If you put startService on Main.java it creates another IntentService.

Comment: Again, I see no point in that. Also, why the while loop? If you want to keep a service alive use a started services not an intent service. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html